# Assigning background image to ExtJs' toolbar

Tags: html, css, background-image, extjs4.1, toolbar

I have a page built using border layout, the north region of which hosts a toolbar. I have some buttons on both, left and right side of the toolbar. The area in the center is unused and I want to put a logo in there.

I have designed a css class for the image and supplied the class name to the bodyCls property of the toolbar. The image logo doesn't however show itself.

Can somebody point out what wrong am I doing or may be suggest a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

See which classes are applied by default to toolbar like .x-toolbar, .x-toolbar-default etc. and then customize according to your requirements.